# Is there any way to return all the console logs from a for loop in a single line?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, console.log

I'm not sure how to ask my question.

What I'm trying to achieve is this.

```
This item color is: red This item number is: 1
This item color is: green This item number is: 2
This item color is: blue This item number is: 3
```

But my function is returning this

```
This item color is: red This item number is: 1
```

```
This item color is: green This item number is: 2
```

```
This item color is: blue This item number is: 3
```

I tried using a newline character (\n) at the end of my console log, but it keeps on printing another line on each loop.

This is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/whmnat0u/

```js
let arr = [{
    number: 1,
    color: "red"
  },
  {
    number: 2,
    color: "green"
  },
  {
    number: 3,
    color: "blue"
  }
]

const returnItems = (list) => {
  let emptyArray = []
  for (const item of list) {
    emptyArray.push({
      number: item.number,
      color: item.color
    })
  }
  printItems(emptyArray);
}

const printItems = (emptyArray) => {
  for (const item of emptyArray) {
    console.log(`This item color is: ${item.color} This item number is: ${item.number}`)
  }
}

returnItems(arr);
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code here. Questions should be self-contained and visitors shouldn't need to go off-site to understand the post or the answers.

Comment: Build up a single string and call `console.log` once after the loop?

Comment: Construct an output string first and then console.log it.

Comment: @mplun You've relicensed the user's code without their permission...

Comment: So op can remove it.

Comment: @mplungjan And yet the code's license remains changed unless the user demands an employee hard-deletes the revisions.

Comment: Ok I’ll bear that in mind. It’s not as if the code is special

Comment: @LGA, do you mind the [license here at SO](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`console.log` will run during each iteration so it makes sense that it outputs the log to the console multiple times. Instead you could store everything in one string and then output that string like this.

```
let message = ''
for (const item of emptyArray) {
    message += `This item color is: ${item.color} This item number is: ${item.number}\n`
}
console.log(message)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is much simplified

I end with a join.

```js
const arr = [{ number: 1, color: "red"   },
             { number: 2, color: "green" },
             { number: 3, color: "blue"  }];

// const valueList = list => list.map(({number,color}) => ({ number, color})); // not used
const printItems = arr => arr.map(item => `This item color is: ${item.color} This item number is: ${item.number}`);
console.log(printItems(arr).join("\n"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to save all of them in a variable and finally console.log that variable once.

```
const printItems = (emptyArray) => {
  let result = ``;
  for (const item of emptyArray) {
    result += `This item color is: ${item.color} This item number is: ${item.number}
`;
  }
  console.log(result);
}
```